# Using multiple backslashes in an Excel cell causes the text to be repeated

Tags: excel

So on one colleagues computer (read their excel session ) if one is to put :

```
\\\\\\hello
```

in a cell, this will just become

```
\\\hello\\\hello\\\hello
```

as wide as the cell will go.   This doesn't happen on my Excel session.  It is quite annoying as we are dealing with network file paths and we can work around by putting the apostrophe before these but I would like to know what is going on.  Has anyone else seen this?

I assume it is in an Excel setting somewhere as I have put `Application.EnableEvents = False` into the Immediate Window and made sure there was nothing untoward in the `Worksheet_Change` event.

Answer (score 1):

If Transition navigation keys is checked with `/` for menu key under Lotus compatibility (Excel Options, Advanced) then entering `\\\hello` will repeat `\\hello\\hello\\hello...`